# Angular 9 Async Validation

Tags: javascript, angular, angular9, angular-validation

I'm trying to write an AsyncValidatorFn in Angular 9 and I've come across an issue.

If I try to introduce a debounce to poll state changes before firing, the function doesn't seem return the error message to my reactive form. Without the debounce it fires perfectly but doesn't poll which in a live environment would be unnecessary traffic to the server. Can anyone take a look at my code and spot the issue?

I've looked around various examples and they all seem to do it this way and claim to work.

```
export function CodeExistsValidator(service: Service): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
        return timer(500).pipe(switchMap(() => {
            return service.checkExists(control.value)
                .pipe(map((response: any) => {
                    return response.data ? { codeExists: true } : null;
                }));
        }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the above works perfectly and the issue was server side. Can't believe I missed it.